# LibreOffice macro get index current sheet

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Does someone know how to get the index of the current sheet in LibreOffice Macro Basic?

I successed to get the name:

```
cursheet = my_doc.getcurrentcontroller.activesheet.Name
```

But how to get index?

Moreover is there a place to find the documentation of all this component and basic language?

TY for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like two qestions in one... Regarding the documentation, you may start at the [OOo Wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide) or the [LO Wiki](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Basic_Help) on Basic, respectively. For a more complete guide, check Andrew Pitonyak's resources on [OpenOffice macros](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php). Usually, all solutions working for OpenOffice.org should work with LO, too.

Regarding the index of the current sheet: as usual, the [OpenOffice.org forums know the answer](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=64279):

> sSheet.RangeAddress.Sheet